# Center nav-brand and menu between 767px and 992px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I read other questions here on stackoverflow but I can't figure out (not working), how to center a navbar menu and logo between 767px and 992px for mobile devices...

For PC is:

```html
----------- simple links menu--
-- logo ------------- navmenu--
```

...and for small devices > 767px and < 992px should be in 3 lines, all centered:

```html
------ simple links menu ------
-------------- logo -----------
------------ navmenu ----------
```

Under 767px it's good - there is a collapse menu...

Here is code only for header nav and full css:

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400italic");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic");

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
General Styles
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

body {
 background: #212121;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
 font: 400 16px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
 color: #eee;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

iframe {
 border: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Selection
------------------------------------------------------------------ */

::-moz-selection {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}

::-webkit-selection {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}

::selection {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Transition elsements
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

a,
.btn {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
      -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
         transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Reset box-shadow
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.btn,
.well,
.panel,
.progress,
.form-control, .form-control:hover, .form-control:focus {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
     -ms-box-shadow: none;
      -o-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Reset border-radius
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.well, .label, .alert,
.modal-content {
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
     -ms-border-radius: 2px;
      -o-border-radius: 2px;
         border-radius: 2px;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Typography
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

a {
 color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.55);
}

a:hover, a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fafafa;
 outline: 0;
}

   
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Tabs and Accordion
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.nav-tabs {
 border-color: #fafafa;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
 font-size: 12px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
      -o-border-radius: 2px;
         border-radius: 2px;
}

.nav-tabs >li.active > a,
.nav-tabs >li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs >li.active > a:focus {
 border: 1px solid #fafafa;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li > a:focus {
 background: #fafafa;
}

.tab-content {
 border: 1px solid #fafafa;
 border-top: 0;
 padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content :last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Navigation
------------------------------------------------------------------- */



.navbar-custom {
 -webkit-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000), padding 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000), padding 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
      -o-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000), padding 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
         transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000), padding 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.300, 0.100, 0.580, 1.000);
}

.navbar-custom {
 background: #212121;
 border: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 12px;
 webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 float: none;
 height: 60px;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fafafa;
}

.navbar-custom a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
 color: #fafafa;
 -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
      -o-transition: none;
         transition: none;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li > a {
 position: relative;
}

.navbar-custom .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
 background: none;
 color: #757575;
}


/* Navbar toggle */

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
 margin-top: 13px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background: #bdbdbd;
}

/* Navbar dropdown */

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
 background: #212121;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 border-radius: 0;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #fafafa;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a {
 border: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 10px;
 padding: 11px 15px;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 right: auto;
 margin-top: -1px;
}

.leftauto {
 right: 0 !important;
 left: auto !important;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu.left-side {

 right: 100%;
 left: auto;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-toggle:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -5px;
 font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
 font-size: 9px;
 content: "\f107";
 text-rendering: auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle {
 padding-right: 28px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 right: 15px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -5px;
 font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
 font-size: 9px;
 content: "\f107";
 text-rendering: auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.light-logo {
 display: none !important;
}

.navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .light-logo {
 display: block !important;
}

.navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .dark-logo {
 display: none !important;
}

/* Push search */

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle.search-dropdown:after {
 content: "";
}

.dropdown-search {
 position: relative;
 padding: 7px 5px;
}

.dropdown-search .form-control {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-search .search-btn {
 position: absolute;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 50%;
 right: 0px;
 width: 42px;
 height: 32px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 14px;
 outline: none;
 color: #fafafa;
 margin-top: -16px;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Hero
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.module-hero {
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
}

.hero-caption {
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.hero-text {
 position: relative;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}

/* Hero caption sizes */

.mh-line-size-1,
.mh-line-size-2,
.mh-line-size-3,
.mh-line-size-4,
.mh-line-size-5,
.mh-line-size-6 {
 font-weight: 700;
 opacity: 0.99;
 margin: 0;
}

.mh-line-size-1 {
 letter-spacing: 50px;
 font-size: 26px;
}

.mh-line-size-2 {
 letter-spacing: 40px;
 font-size: 24px;
}

.mh-line-size-3 {
 letter-spacing: 12px;
 font-size: 22px;
}

.mh-line-size-4 {
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.mh-line-size-5 {
 letter-spacing: 6px;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.mh-line-size-6 {
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 16px;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules
------------------------------------------------------------------- */


.amber {color: ;}

.wrapper {
 background: #212121;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
}


.module,
.module-small {
 padding: 140px 0;
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
}

.module-small {
 padding: 70px 0;
}

.navbar-custom + .module {
 padding: 200px 0;
}

.navbar-custom + .module-small {
 padding: 130px 0;
}

.module-parallax {
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* Module titles */

.module-title {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.module-subtitle {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.module-icon {
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.module-title + .module-subtitle {
 margin-top: -35px;
}

.divider {
 margin: 0;
}

.copyright {
 padding: 0 5px;
}



/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
Responsive Media Queries
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

 /* Navbar */

 .navbar-nav {
  margin: 5px -15px;
}

 .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .navbar-transparent {
  background: transparent;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
 }

 /* Tra */

 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .navbar-nav > li > a,
 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #212121;
 }

 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .nav > li > a:focus,
 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .nav > li > a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
 }

 .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 9px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  content: "\f105";
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 }

 .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
 }

 .navbar-custom .open > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
 }

 .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
 }

 /* Comments */

 .comment .comment {
  margin-left: 100px;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 992px) {

 /* Hero captions */

 .mh-line-size-1 {
  letter-spacing: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-2 {
  letter-spacing: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-3 {
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-4 {
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 .navbar-custom {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 /* Portfolio grid */

 .work-item,
 .grid-sizer {
  width: 33.3333%;
 }

 .work-item.wide,
 .work-item.wide-tall {
  width: 66.6666%;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

 /* Navbar */

 .navbar-custom {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
 }

 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .light-logo {
  display: none !important;
 }

 .navbar-transparent.navbar-dark .dark-logo {
  display: block !important;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  padding: 10px 25px;
 }

 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header,
 .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  padding: 10px 35px;
 }

 .navbar-custom .dropdown-toggle:after, .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .dropdown-toggle:after {
  right: 15px;
  content: "\f107";
 }

 .navbar-custom .nav > .open >.dropdown-toggle:after, .navbar-custom .dropdown-menu .dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle:after {
  right: 15px;
  content: "\f106";
 }

 /* Hero captions */

 .mh-line-size-1 {
  letter-spacing: 24px;
  font-size: 26px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-2 {
  letter-spacing: 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-3 {
  letter-spacing: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-4 {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-5 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-6 {
  font-size: 13px;
 }



 /* Portfolio filters */

 .filters li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
 }

 .filters li:last-child {
  margin: 0 10px 140px;
 }

 /* Portfolio grid */

 .work-item,
 .grid-sizer {
  width: 50%;
 }

 .work-item.wide,
 .work-item.wide-tall {
  width: 100%;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 500px) {

 /* Hero captions */

 .mh-line-size-1 {
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  font-size: 26px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-2 {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-3 {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-4 {
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-5 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 11px;
 }

 .mh-line-size-6 {
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 /* Portfolio grid */

 .work-item,
 .grid-sizer {
  width: 100%;
 }

 .work-item.wide,
 .work-item.wide-tall {
  width: 100%;
 }

}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
Multi-columns-row
------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.multi-columns-row .first-in-row {
 clear: left;
}

.multi-columns-row .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: left; }
.multi-columns-row .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: left; }
.multi-columns-row .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: left; }
.multi-columns-row .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: left; }
.multi-columns-row .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: left; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {

 .multi-columns-row .col-xs-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-xs-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-xs-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-xs-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-xs-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: none; }

 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: left; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-sm-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: none; }

 .multi-columns-row .col-md-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: left; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

 .multi-columns-row .col-md-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: none; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-md-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: none; }

 .multi-columns-row .col-lg-6:nth-child(2n + 3) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-lg-4:nth-child(3n + 4) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-lg-3:nth-child(4n + 5) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-lg-2:nth-child(6n + 7) { clear: left; }
 .multi-columns-row .col-lg-1:nth-child(12n + 13) { clear: left; }

}

.et-icons .box1 {
 border: 1px solid #fafafa;
 display: block;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

.et-icons .box1 > span {
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 1px solid #fafafa;
 min-width: 60px;
 min-height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 28px;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.fa-icons {
 padding: 0 15px;
}
.fa-icons > div {
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #fafafa;
 margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.fa-icons > div > i {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 min-width: 40px;
 min-height: 40px;
 border-right: 1px solid #fafafa;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
}



/*  ------- CUSTOM Styles ------*/


h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small, .h1 small, .h2 small, .h3 small, .h4 small, .h5 small, .h6 small, h1 .small, h2 .small, h3 .small, h4 .small, h5 .small, h6 .small, .h1 .small, .h2 .small, .h3 .small, .h4 .small, .h5 .small, .h6 .small {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}



.amber {color: #EB9532;}

.text-21 {color: #212121 !important;}

.bk h1, .bk  .h1,
.bk h5, .bk .h5
 {
 line-height: 1.4;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #212121 !important;
}

.module-divider {

 height: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #212121;

}

.vofset { padding-top: 5px !important; padding-bottom: 5px !important;}
.vofset0 { padding-top: 0px; }
.vofset1 { padding-top: 10px; }
.vofset2 { padding-top: 20px; }
.vofset3 { padding-top: 30px; }
.vofset4 { padding-top: 40px; }
.vofset5 { padding-top: 50px; }
.vofset7 { padding-top: 70px; }
.vofset10 { padding-top: 100px; }
.vofset12 { padding-top: 120px; }
.vofset14 { padding-top: 140px; }

.lofset1 { padding-bottom: 10px; }
.lofset2 { padding-bottom: 20px; }
.lofset3 { padding-bottom: 30px; }
.lofset4 { padding-bottom: 40px; }
.lofset5 { padding-bottom: 50px; }
.lofset7 { padding-bottom: 70px; }
.lofset10 { padding-bottom: 100px; }
.lofset12 { padding-bottom: 120px; }
.lofset14 { padding-bottom: 140px; }

.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}






.navbar {
 min-height: 90px;
}

.navbar-custom {
 padding-top: 10px;

}

.navbar-top {
 padding: 5px 0px;
 margin: 0px -15px;
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #9e9e9e;
 background: #212121;
}

.navbar-top a {
 
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px !important;
 color: #9e9e9e;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    font: "Lato", sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-duration: 0s;
 transition-property: none;
 transition-timing-function: ease;


}

.navbar-top a:hover {
 color: #eee;

}


.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: #e9e9e9;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 navbar-top hidden-xs">
     Simple Links Here
   </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <!-- YOU LOGO HERE -->
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <!-- IMAGE OR SIMPLE TEXT -->
    <img class="dark-logo" src="assets/images/top_logo_3.png" width="220" alt="">
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="custom-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Multi Page</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Parallax</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-2.html">Film overlay</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-3.html">Slider</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-4.html">Text rotator</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-5.html">Youtube background</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">One page</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="op-index.html">Parallax</a></li>
        <li><a href="op-index-2.html">Film overlay</a></li>
        <li><a href="op-index-3.html">Slider</a></li>
        <li><a href="op-index-4.html">Text rotator</a></li>
        <li><a href="op-index-5.html">Youtube background</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pages</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="about-1.html">About 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="about-2.html">About 2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="services-1.html">Services 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-2.html">Services 2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="contact-1.html">Contact 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact-2.html">Contact 2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Pricing</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="pricing-1.html">Pricing 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing-2.html">Pricing 2</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="login-register.html">Login / Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq-1.html">FAQ</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Features</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="components-buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-icons.html">Icons</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-boxes.html">Content boxes</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-typography.html">Typography</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-bars.html">Progress bars</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-tabs.html">Tab & Accordian</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-tables.html">Pricing tables</a></li>
      <li><a href="components-modules.html">Modules & Overlays</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact-1.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->
```

Comment: you can add `navbar{text-align:center;}` in the media query

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[image]

Put this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
   .navbar-header {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 50%;
}
   .navbar-brand {
display: inline-block;
}
img.dark-logo {
text-align: center;
}
div#custom-collapse {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50%;
}
.nav .navbar-nav .navbar-right {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

}
```

Comment: not working... i tryed this with: @media screen and (max-width: 992px) { .navbar-header { width: 100%; } img.dark-logo { text-align: center; } }

Comment: Then you should try it with margin: 0 auto; instead of using text-align:center;